# Given the eigendecomposition of a positive semidefinite, singular matrix $A$, how to determine if a small perturbation $A + \delta A$ is indefinite

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, orthogonality, perturbation-theory

Given the eigendecomposition of a positive semidefinite, singular matrix $A$, is there a good way to determine if a small perturbation $A + \delta A$ is indefinite?  Here, the perturbation $\delta A$ is also symmetric.

If $A$ and $\delta A$ shared the same eigenspace, then we could simply look at the eigenvalues and if the corresponding of eigenvalue of $\delta A$ to a zero eigenvalue of $A$ was negative, then the resulting perturbation would be indefinite.  However, there are perturbations orthogonal to the eigenspace of $A$ that also cause the resulting sum to become indefinite and I'm not sure how to check those.

For example, consider the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\\\1/2 & 1/2 & 0\\\\0 & 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
with eigenvalues 0, 1, and 1.  The perturbation
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1/\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0\\\\0 & -1/\sqrt{2} & 0\\\\0 & 0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}
$$
causes $A + \epsilon \delta A$ to be indefinite for $\epsilon > 0$ and $\delta A$ is orthogonal to eigenspace of $A$.  I'd like a way to check these cases.